# Why i can't access list of array in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I fetch some date and get array and i can console.log and see all staff but when i try map or access of some elements from array i got error undefined...

and get this 
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
  const [key, setKey] = useState(false);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState([]);
  const [nextFive, setFive] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getWeather();
  }, [key]);


  const getCity = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const cityName = e.target.elements.cityName.value;
    const api_call = await fetch(`http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY}&q=${cityName}&details=true`);
    const data = await api_call.json();
    setKey(data[0].Key);
    setCountry(data[0]);
    return data[0].Key;
  }


    const getWeather = async (cityKey = key) => { 
      const proxy = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`;
      const link = `${proxy}http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/5day/${cityKey}?apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY}&details=true&metric=true`;

      const api_call = await fetch(link);
      const data = await api_call.json();
      setFive(data.DailyForecasts);

    };


console.log(nextFive); if i tray console.log(nextFive[0].something) i will get error  :) 
console.log(country);

      {
        nextFive.map((item) => {
          return <p>{item.Date}</p>
        })
      }
```

and get this Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: it will be very helpful if you'd provide code demo like code codesandbox, jsfiddle or simialr

Answer (score 0):

This happends because you try to show first element of item in array that is **not yet populated**.

You could have extra hook called as example **weatherLoading**, once api call is succesfuly you would set status of weatherLoading to true and then simply do this:

```
weatherLoading && console.log(nextFive[0].something)
```